# How do I get every Input element within the Power App Vertical gallery, Getting the last value every time

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I am trying to create dynamic input components in the power apps for that I have used Vertical Gallery, and Within that vertical gallery I have a Horizontal container to align the inputs properly, and then I have several inputs under it. I am trying to get the input values from the gallery using "ForAll" loop but I am getting the value of the last Item only.

Below is the structure of the gallery

```
 DynamicComponentsGallery
 ---- HorizontalContainer
 ---- ---- Input1Text
 ---- ---- Input2Date
 ---- ---- Input3Text
 ---- ---- AddNewElementToGalleryButton
```

suppose I have 2 rows In my gallery and I have inserted the records like this

```
Test1Rec1         20/08/2022       Test1Rec2
Test2Rec1         12/12/2022       Test2Rec2
```

Every time I try to fetch the record using "ForAll"

```
ForAll(DynamicComponentsGallery.AllItems, {
  input1 : Input1Text.Text,
  input2 : Text(Input2Date.SelectedDate, DateTimeFormat.ShortDate),
  input3 : Input3Text.Text,
});
```

I Always get 2 record with the values

```
Test2Rec1         12/12/2022       Test2Rec2
Test2Rec1         12/12/2022       Test2Rec2
```

Same Goes for any number of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that I have a gallery with 2 items and each item has a textbox for the user to input some data. Here's how I would have on the button:

```
// clear the collection to avoid accidental clicks on the button
Clear(ColOutput);

// ForAll loop running on the gallery to collect each textbox response in the collection
ForAll(Gallery.AllItems, Collect(ColOutput, {TextboxOutputs:TextInput.Text}));
```

Comment: Does this still work if there are items in the gallery that you don't want to take the text from, e.g. buttons?